# How to restore default keyboard after add toolbar (iphone)

Tags: iphone, keyboard

I have a custom keyboard with toolbar on the top. But i want to get default keyboard because i only want to use the custom keyboard in one view. In other view, i want to use default keyboard.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {   
    for (UIWindow *keyboardWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        // Now iterating over each subview of the available windows
        for (UIView *keyboard in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {
            // Check to see if the description of the view we have referenced is UIKeyboard.
            // If so then we found the keyboard view that we were looking for.
            //NSLog(@"keyboard %@",keyboard);
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES){
                NSValue *v = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey];
                CGRect kbBounds = [v CGRectValue];
                if(keyboardToolbar == nil) {
                    keyboardToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
                    keyboardToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
                    //keyboardToolbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
                    UIBarButtonItem *flex = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
                    NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:flex, barButtonItem, nil];
                    [keyboardToolbar setItems:items];
                    [barButtonItem release];
                    [flex release];
                    [items release];
                }
                [keyboardToolbar removeFromSuperview];
                keyboardToolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kbBounds.size.width, 30);

                [keyboard addSubview:keyboardToolbar];
                keyboard.bounds = CGRectMake(kbBounds.origin.x, kbBounds.origin.y, kbBounds.size.width, kbBounds.size.height + 60);
                for(UIView* subKeyboard in [keyboard subviews]) {
                    if([[subKeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboardImpl"] == YES) {                       
                        subKeyboard.bounds = CGRectMake(kbBounds.origin.x, kbBounds.origin.y - 30, kbBounds.size.width, kbBounds.size.height);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on how you added the toolbar to your keyboard.
Generally I guess `toolbar.hidden = YES` could be a good solution.

Comment: No, because when i add a toolbar to custom keyboard, the position of keyboard was changed. Cause, i must restore the keyboard position. I did it manually. But i want to know have any method from the API to restore keyboard default.

Comment: it would be easier knowing your code. there is more than one way to add toolbar to a keyboard: which is your? are you subclassing the keyboard? are you adding the toolbar using UIKeyboardWillShowNotification? what do you mean with "the position of keyboard was changed"? where is it?

Comment: I added the toolbar using UIKeyboardWillShowNotification. I've updated my code. As you see, the bound of subKeyboard and keyboard was changed.